# update date to next day in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to update my date to next day date. How Can I do it?

Now I do it using this.

```
$calendar = Calendar::find($id);
$calendar->update(['started_at' => $calendar->started_at->addDay(1)));
```

or I can do it

```
$calendar->started_at->addDay(1);
$calendar->save();
```

But this solutions is bad for me because there are **2 request in database**. I wont do it using only one request.

Is there a way to dynamically update date to next day date?

For example

```
Calendar::where('id', $id)->updateToNextDay('started_at');
```

I find also sql equivalent

```
UPDATE `calendar` SET `started_at` = `started_at` - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Thanks for attention.

Comment: What's wrong with the first solution? And no, there's no built-in way to do this out of the box. You could extend the query builder and add it yourself, but that's a very dirty hack...

Comment: You could also create a function within the Calendar model to add a day.

Comment: The first solution is bad because it do 2 request in databse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Calendar::where('id', $id)->update()` is just syntactical sugar.  This proxies you to the Query Builder and is the same as running `DB::table('calendar')->where('id', $id)->update();`

The power of a model in an ORM is obtaining the data from the database, mapping it to properties in an object, and then manipulating that object.  The overhead of a single select for an update is pretty small and if you're worried about that overhead in the development phase, you're probably overoptimizing.

If you wish to forego the select, you can use the Query Builder with a raw SQL expression. Either will call the Query Builder and run the same exact query:

```
Calendar::where('id', $id)
    ->update(['started_at' => DB::raw("started_at + INTERVAL 1 DAY")]);
```

or

```
DB::table('calendars')->where('id', $id)
    ->update(['started_at' => DB::raw("started_at + INTERVAL 1 DAY")]);
```

Comment: First solution result is **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;.....**  and i wont to use eloquent model no DB facade

Comment: @Davit Read what I wrote, they both do the same thing.

Comment: Swapped the 1 and day around, they were in the wrong order.

Comment: Your answer is detailed explained what done in Laravel. For explanation upvote. but it is does not solution of my answer

Comment: I updated your answer for use eloquent model functions. If you suggest me can confirm it,

Comment: That won't work because you aren't inside of an instance.  When you use `Calendar::where()`, you aren't returning an instance of Calendar, you're returning an instance of Eloquent Builder.  You also want to be careful putting variables directly into a raw expression, if they are ever sourced by user input, you'll be subject to an injection attack.

Comment: Ok i forgotten about injection attack

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Calendar::where('id', $id)->update([
  'started_at' => DB::raw("DATE_ADD(started_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)")
]);
```

Let me know :)

Comment: result is **date_add() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given**

Comment: What is the datatype of `started_at`?

Comment: @Davit Updated my answer. Check now.

Comment: Call to undefined function CalendarServices\STR_TO_DATE()

Comment: @Davit I was missing string notations in DB::Raw. LOL Sry. Should work now.

Comment: It is also **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

Comment: @Davit Final answer. Check now.

Comment: I try also @Devon answer and it is solve my problem. For your effort to help me upvote. Thank you

Comment: @Davit Yeah, its okay. No worries. Your problem is solved so *thumbs-up*

Answer (score 0):

```
$startDate = date_timestamp_get($calendar->started_at);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', $startDate));
$calendar->update(['started_at' => $date]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own method in Calendar model like,

```
public function updateToNextDay(string $column)
{
    $this->update([
        $column => \Db::raw("$column + INTERVAL DAY 1");
    ]);
}
```

Not tested, but it should work.

Comment: It is a two request in db. I wont do it using only one request

Comment: @Davit What is the datatype of your column started_at?

Comment: datetime.  I find sql equivalent **UPDATE `calendar`
    SET `started_at` = `started_at` - INTERVAL 1 DAY;**

Comment: Check DB::raw, validate the raw query.

Comment: The updated answer also won't complete what they want since to get to this point, you would have already contacted the database and retrieved the model.

Comment: I can do it using DB::raw but for me priority use eloquent model then DB fasade

Comment: @Davit, I don't think you understand what an Eloquent model is.  To use the model itself, you would have to select the data from the database, that's how an ORM works.  Otherwise, you just use the Query Builder.  DB::raw() just formats a raw expression, it can be used by either the model or the query builder.

Comment: Dude, the core idea of Model is to fetch the model and then update, it helps with collections too. Since you don't want two queries, you have to go raw and rough.

Comment: I can do it for owerriding same method of eloquent  **public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        return new ExtendedBuilder($query);
    }** and add in ExtendedBuilder method **updateToNextDay()**

Comment: @Devon It works with facade, method is not static but yeah, there will be only single update call as only the model object is instanced.